# TikZ: Drawing an ellipse through two points

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am trying to construct a portion of an ellipse that connects point `P1` and `P2` but I don't know anything about the ellipse besides that `F` is one of the foci.  All I know is that an elliptic arc connects the two points.  I tried using `\draw let ...` and then specifying the start and end angle but I don't what the x radius and y radius would be nor the orientation of the ellipse.  Any ideas on how to construct this?  I have a similar question which never received a definitive answer since it was more restrictive.  That post can be found here [ellipse intersecting a circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109507/ellipse-intersecting-a-circle/109529#109529) but I was just winging it there.

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz, intersections}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 4pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =,
    line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45
    ]

    \node[scale = .75, fill = black, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F)
    at (0, 0) {};
    \node[scale = .75, fill = black, big dot = {below: \(P_1\)}] (P1)
    at (2, 0) {};
    \node[scale = .75, fill = black, big dot = {above, right = .25cm: \(P2\)}]
    (P2) at (-2, 2) {};
    \draw[-latex] (F) -- (P1) node[scale = .75, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm,
    shape = circle, pos = .5] {\(\mathbf{r}_1\)};
    \draw[-latex] (F) -- (P2) node[scale = .75, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm,
    shape = circle, pos = .5] {\(\mathbf{r}_2\)};
    \draw (-1, 0) -- (F);
    \draw let
      \p0 = (F),
      \p1 = (P1),
      \p2 = (P2),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.4cm}
    in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc [radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[scale = .75, pos = .5, above = .4cm] {\(\Delta\nu\)};
    \draw (P1) -- (P2) node[scale = .75, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm,
    shape = circle, pos = .5] {\(c\)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is underspecified, you need [at least five points to define an ellipse](http://sarcasticresonance.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/how-many-points-does-it-take-to-define/) (or some other information like the eccentricity and the rotation)

Comment: @Jake unfortunately, that is all the information I have.

Comment: I am interested to know how to do an arc of an ellipse given 3 points and the 2 radii lengths, and I don't want full ellipse, just the elliptical arc through the 3 points.

Comment: @ADP it is a tough problem to handle with so little information.

Comment: @Jake would it be possible to use intersections on an ellipse we need to construct through the two points with the focus `F`?

Comment: Seems to me there are two parts to this question: (1) A geometry problem -- how to construct an ellpse from end-points and focus, and (2) how to draw the thing in tikz. You might have more luck getting an answer to part #1 on math.stackexchange.

Comment: From your picture, it seems that F lies on a line connecting the midpoint of the ellipse and P1? Do you also know the midpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as Jake commented you have an underdefined problem so the best approach is the manually placed arc and be done with it. Because to automate it, you **have** to supply more info. A possibility is to make a quarter arc directly

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 1pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 2pt, dot = {#1}},
    line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45
    ]
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F) at (0, 0) {};
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {below: \(P_1\)}] (P1)  at (2, 0) {};
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {above right=.25cm:\(P_2\)}] (P2) at (-2, 2) {};

    \draw let
      \p0 = ($(P2)-(F)$),
      \p1 = ($(P1)-(P2)$)
    in  (P2|-P1) ++(\x1,0) arc (0:270:\x1 and \y0);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

A possible visual solution is to add

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 1pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 2pt, dot = {#1}},
    line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45
    ]
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F) at (0, 0) {};
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {below: \(P_1\)}] (P1)  at (2, 0) {};
    \node[ fill = black, big dot = {above right=.25cm:\(P_2\)}] (P2) at (-2, 2) {};    

    \begin{scope}[decoration={%
        markings,%
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[line width=0.4pt]{triangle 45}}%
        },
    ]
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{P1}{center}}
    \pgfpatharcto{2.55cm}{4cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointanchor{P2}{center}}
    \pgfgetpath\temppath
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgfsetpath\temppath
    \pgfdecoratecurrentpath{markings}
    \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted to added an arrow at pos = .5 of to this path: `\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{P1}{center}}
    \pgfpatharcto{2.55cm}{4cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointanchor{P2}{center}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}` How can this be done?

Comment: @dustin See the edit

Comment: @percusse: Maybe I'm getting something wrong here, but I think your second solution doesn't actually solve the problem: `(F)` isn't a focus of the ellipse in this case.

Comment: @Jake No you are right. But you can make it *look-like* it is a focal point otherwise there is an underdefined set of equations that needs to be dealt with. With a slight nudge, you can consider (F) as the focal point of the ellipse almost vertical but tilted a little to the left. But to be honest I don't feel like going through all the computations to fix an approximation that would visually won't matter much... But, if you have a better alternative, please go ahead.

Comment: @percusse: Oh no, no way, doing this properly would be way too much work (can we solve linear equation systems in LaTex?), especially, as you say, since it's just a visual approximation. Sorry for the nitpickery `=)`

Comment: @Jake No problem at all. In another news, I'm kinda solving linear equations now but far from production state :) `fpu` is really difficult to tame, L3 is difficult to learn heh.